# Package fail on CRAN due to test using testthat

Tags: r, cran, testthat

I submitted my package to CRAN and it did not pass the CRAN R CMD check.
This is the error they get:

```
* checking tests ... ERROR
Running the tests in ‘tests/testthat.R’ failed.
Last 13 lines of output:
  Type 'contributors()' for more information and
  'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

  Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
  'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
  Type 'q()' to quit R.

  > library(testthat)
  > library(prepdat)
  >
  > test_check("prepdat")
  Error: On CRAN
  testthat results     ================================================================
  OK: 0 SKIPPED: 0 FAILED: 0
  Execution halted
```

and this is how my test file looks (and here is a link to GitHub https://github.com/ayalaallon/prepdat

```
skip_on_cran()
library(prepdat)
data("finalized_stroopdata")
data("stroopdata")

context("Finalized table")

test_finalized_stroopdata <- prep(
  dataset = stroopdata
  , file_name = NULL
  , file_path = NULL
  , id = "subject"
  , within_vars = c("block", "target_type")
  , between_vars = c("order")
  , dvc = "rt"
  , dvd = "ac"
  , keep_trials = NULL
  , drop_vars = c()
  , keep_trials_dvc = "raw_data$rt > 100 & raw_data$rt < 3000 & raw_data$ac     == 1"
  , keep_trials_dvd = "raw_data$rt > 100 & raw_data$rt < 3000"
  , id_properties = c()
  , sd_criterion = c(1, 1.5, 2)
  , percentiles = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.75, 0.95)
  , outlier_removal = 2
  , keep_trials_outlier = "raw_data$ac == 1"
  , decimal_places = 0
  , notification = TRUE
  , dm = c()
  , save_results = FALSE
  , results_name = "results.txt"
  , results_path = NULL
  , save_summary = FALSE
)

test_that("Finialized table is correct", {
  expect_equal(test_finalized_stroopdata, finalized_stroopdata)
})
```

How can I fix this?

Any help will be very much appreciated,

Ayala

Comment: Your intent is unclear to me. Do you want this to be skipped on CRAN?

Comment: Yes. It fails on CRAN check although I have skip_on_cran()

Comment: I think you need to include `skip_on_cran()` in your `test_that` code block. Could you try that?

Comment: Thanks! Looking much better https://win-builder.r-project.org/S7m87yL2xI2f/00check.log

Comment: Should I run more checks before submitting to CRAN again?

Comment: Thank you so much! The new version is on CRAN now https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prepdat/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `skip_on_cran` incorrectly. It needs to be contained within your `test_that` block:

```
test_that("Finialized table is correct", {
  skip_on_cran()
  expect_equal(test_finalized_stroopdata, finalized_stroopdata)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. All the code except `context()` should be inside `test_that` as can be seen here https://github.com/ayalaallon/prepdat/blob/master/tests/testthat/test_prep.R